# PHP exec() continuously gets re-created

Tags: php

I need a help to understand why PHP script process continuously gets re-created a script started by exec() in background on CentOS. This script runs for many years under EasyApache3 PHP 5.4, after the update to EasyApache4 and PHP 5.6 the behavior changes.

====< PHP 01 >====

```
<html><body>
    Test <? echo "Date: " . date("d/m/Y h:i:sa");?> - run PHP exec () that call a second script in background.php script.<br><br>
    The script create a txt file.<br><br><br><br>
    <a href="http://domain/index.php"  class="login_admin">Return to homepage....</a>
</body></html>
<?PHP
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    echo "<script language=\"javascript\"> window.alert('The create txt file process will be started in background.'); </script>";
    exec("php -f /full_path/a_teste_exec_03_background.php > /full_path/a_teste_03.txt &", $o, $v);
    print_r($o);
    echo $v;
?>
```

====< PHP 02 >====

```
<?PHP
    $a_teste_log  = fopen("a_teste_03_log.txt","a");
    $linha_log    = "\n\r" . date("Y-m-d h:i:sa") . " - Creation file...\n\r";
    fwrite($a_teste_log, $linha_log);
    fclose($a_teste_log);
    exit;
?>
```

Looking at the server there are a lot of PHP02 process, with different PIDs, and only stop after consuming resources and send the error message below:

```
    PHP Warning:  
    exec(): Unable to fork 
    [php -f /fullpath/a_teste_exec_03_background.php &gt; 
        /fullpath/a_teste_03.txt &amp;] 
        in /fullpath/a_teste_exec_03.php on line nn
```

What is wrong? How to fix? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Check your web server logs to see if anything is accessing that file that you don't know about it (bots, perhaps). Leaving a script like this open to the web can be a very bad idea.

Comment: The file is created by the script 02, there aren't any other file access... This is an example.

Answer (score 0):

After the update of EasyApache3 to EasyApache4 and PHP from 5.4 to 5.6, something change the behavior about creating process when using PHP exec() command.

Finally, after many tests, I understand that the owner of a process started in background is different from when you start using a browser.

What I did, create a shell script, under the same domain that start the URL php script. Into this shell I run a wget command:

Resuming, the first PHP script run the command:

exec("./script_exec_background.sh > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");

... and the shell contains

#!/bin/bash
wget -q http://www.domain/xxx/yyy/database_update.php

Both scripts needs to run under same domain and all works fine.